# Add Hibernate entity with foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, rest

I am building a (spring boot) rest service and I seem to have some fundamental misunderstanding of Hibernate and foreign keys or whatever.

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
public class ClassA {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "class_b", nullable = false)
    private ClassB classB;

  // more properties and getters/setters left out for brevity
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "class_b")
public class ClassB {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

  // more properties and getters/setters left out for brevity
}
```

ClassA has a foreign key to ClassB. I want my user to be able to give me an instance of classA, e.g.

```
{ //instance of class A, e.g. via POST
  id: 19,
  class_b_id: 17
}
```

That means, I get an id for class A and the id from class B. If I wanted to create an entity of class A and save it in the database I have to retrieve the corresponding instance of class B first, call setClassB(...) and then save the instance to the database.

And my entity might even have more foreign keys to more entities which I have to retrieve first, including their properties etc. just to save my new entity.

Is that the way it is supposed to be? Or do I miss something here? Is there a way to define the entity in a way that I can use the foreign keys the way I get them? (And I don't mean: "Don't use hibernate") Without retrieving other objects first?

It just feels wrong and unnessecary.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a bidirectional relationship between those entities and use classB to cascade the creation of classA? This way you get the creation/update at once and don't have to retrieve and set the relations manually.

As in your example, you get the id of classA to be created but also class_b_id that you can use to fetch classB instance and proceed with classA creation, that will be attached to classB.